# Is it possible to have a race condition with injection tokens in Angular?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

We have been using an implementations module with great success for a number of years:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: TOKEN_A, useClass: A_Impl},
    {provide: TOKEN_B, useClass: B_Impl},
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppImplsModule {}
```

Then that module is imported in the `imports` of AppModule.
We are trying to upgrade from Angular 10 to Angular 12.  I am now sometimes getting errors when I run the application such as:

> NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken TOKEN_A

The application will fail to run for x number of attempts.  Then it will run fine for a while.  Then I'll get another NullInjectorError, but for a different token.  I can't find any kind of pattern for when it works versus when it does not.  I don't know if this is related to a change somewhere in Angular 11 or 12, or if there is something else happening.

Does anyone have any ideas for what is wrong, or even how to debug the issue?

**Update:**
I am seeing this issue in a lazy-loaded module.  I've done a little more debugging and found something interesting.  The token is provided and available just fine in a ***component***.  However, later, when the token is injected into another ***service***, that is where it is not available.  Was a change made regarding injecting things into a service??

Comment: Is that module lazy loaded? Or if not, does the order of that module in your import array make a difference?

Comment: @MikeOne See update in post.

Comment: Not sure about relevant changes in provider functionally between 10 and 12, however, because it is lazy loaded, you might be seeing a race condition here. Maybe have a look at forwardRef? (https://angular.io/api/core/forwardRef)